# Add some code to an element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a line of html:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-prev=".butleft" data-cycle-next=".butright" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"  data-cycle-swipe="true" data-cycle-swipe-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-timeout=0  data-cycle-slides="section">
```

And this is the code

```
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
if (jQuery(window).width() <= 992){ 
jQuery("div.cycle-slideshow" ).append( "data-cycle-auto-height='container'" );  
}
```

});

And I want to add this "data-cycle-auto-height='container'" to the elment when the window resizes. However my code isn't working.

Comment: Use `attr` to add new attribute to element, or in your case for data-* attributes use `data()`

Comment: @Tushar - `data()` won't add an attribute.

Comment: @PranavCBalan - what's your point? are you trying to support my comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** does insert a new element to selected div, to add attributes use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to add attribute to an element

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() <= 992) {
    jQuery("div.cycle-slideshow").attr("data-cycle-auto-height", "container");
  }
});
```

Also as @IsmaelMiguel suggested, you can use **[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** to add custom data attribute

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() <= 992) {
    jQuery("div.cycle-slideshow").data("cycle-auto-height", "container");
  }
});
```

Comment: An alternative would be using `jQuery('div.cycle-slideshow').data('cycle-auto-height', 'container');`, but I can't recall if it will map those values to attributes in the DOM.

Comment: I don't disagree. I'm just saying a possible alternative.

Comment: @befranga : glad to help